# How to access a column of a DataFrame from a passed variable in Shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a simple shiny app where the user can select a variable from a drop down menu and then a plot is generated. The selected variable is seen as input$Feature w/in the server function but I am getting errors when trying to access the column of my data frame as df$input$Feature. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
bw <- read.xls('filename')

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'Feature',
               label = 'Select a feature to plot:',
               c(colnames(bw))),
  plotOutput('graph')
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(bw, aes(bw$Date))
    p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=bw$input$Feature, colour='red', group=1))
    p <- p + labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Feature Name')
    print(p)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in the geom_line instead:

```
bw[,input$Feature]
```

Can't be of much more help without having a reproducible example to work with.

EDIT:
This worked for me:

```
bw <- mtcars
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'Feature',
               label = 'Select a feature to plot:',
               c(colnames(bw)),
               selected=colnames(bw)[1]),
  verbatimTextOutput('value'),
  plotOutput('graph')
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$value <- renderPrint(columname())
  columname <- reactive({input$Feature})
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(bw, aes(bw$qsec))+ geom_line(aes_string(y=bw[, input$Feature]))
    p <- p + labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Feature Name')
    p
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: "Error in '[.data.frame'(bw, , input$Feature) : object 'input' not found"

Comment: Yeah, you're also misspelling "selecteInput"